# Why Action In console was Paused till the process is done

Tags: vba, excel

When I use the python or etc,
In using for'for' command,
I print the row count

Beacause it can help to expect how long does it takes time,

But In VBA, Printing line numbers in console is paused when it reach some levels

However, the process is still operating normally.

when it process is done, 
suddenly all output messages are displayed on the console at once.

The performance of the PC is very good. ( i7 CPU  / ram = 16gb)
Why happen like this?

I used below code,
Please refer to this code and capture.

for RowVarialbe = 2 to 100000

debug.print (RowVariable)

next RowVarialbe

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I have observed the same. Add a

```
DoEvents
```

inside the loop and you'll be fine. It'll slow down the process slightly, so you might want to do it every nth row instead (but if performance is an issue, you shouldn't use the console that much - it is a performance killer). Another bonus is that the DoEvents allows you to pause or halt the execution.

Comment: Perfect guide!, Thank you, it was  intentional stopping console for performance